# PostgreSQL jsonb with dynamic attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, entity-attribute-value

I have a table products with ID and jsonb:

```
prod_id|attributes
1| {"3": 17, "4": 50, "5": 195}
```

And I have a table attributes, that contains the name and id for each attribute:

```
attr_id|name
3|width
4|size
5|height
6|color
```

I would like to have the attributes be user definable as it can vary based on products.

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
SELECT name
FROM attributes
WHERE attr_id = (SELECT attributes->>'3' AS attr_id FROM products)
```

What am I doing wrong? And is this the correct approach?

---

Expected result:

```
prod_id|width|size|height
1      |17   |50  |195
```

Comment: Which result are you looking for?

Comment: @GMB Just updated the question please take a look

Comment: If the list of columns is not pre-defined (ie if it varies according to the data), then you need *dynamic* SQL, which is much more complicated. On the other hand, using regular SQL you can have this resultset as rows instead - or as a json object: it this something you could live with?

Comment: @GMB well no because the data is user defined, too many different attributes for many different products. EAVs are not recommended from what I read, so this approach is the next best thing... or so I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the `attributes` table onto the keys of the JSON object, reaggregating for use later to retrieve the keys in the desired columns:

```
select t1.prod_id, t1.js -> 'width', t1.js -> 'size', t1.js -> 'height' 
from (select p.prod_id, (select jsonb_object_agg(a.name, v.value) 
         from jsonb_each(p.attributes) v join attributes a on a.attr_id = v.key::int) js   
      from products p
) t1
```

[Try it online!](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q4HHZxQx)